# Identify the td which was clicked in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a table like below

[image]
(full screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mluq.png)

Here you can see the "down" arrow on some `td`.

for example the `<td>` for 2nd row and 4th column is:

```
<td>
   <a href="doc4.html" name="doc4" target="_blank">doc4</a>
   <span class="arrow"></span>
   <div class="toggle" style="display: none;">
      <div><a href="image_3.1.jpg" name="image" target="_blank">image</a></div>
      <div><a href="testingwrongtype_2.2.gif" name="testingwrongtype" target="_blank">testingwrongtype</a></div>
      <div><a href="vsd_2_1.2.png" name="vsd_2" target="_blank">vsd_2</a></div>
      <div><a href="BMP_1.3.bmp" name="BMP" target="_blank">BMP</a></div>
   </div>
</td>
```

Say if user clicks on arrow of "2nd row and 4th column (which is doc4)" then I want to get the row number in some variable for that.

`var row_clicked = 2`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you build the table yourself? If so, when you recurse over the rows and cells you can add in data attributes to the cell to say what col/row it's in.

Comment: Check sample Here  http://jsfiddle.net/Tn58J/

Comment: @Kiranramchandran: You used `var trindex=$(this).parent().parent().index();
    alert(trindex);`. I did the same in my application but there it gives -1 whereas in fiddle it's showing correct. Any idea what things can be different in my application?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Tn58J/ fiddle...

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)** or **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** to get the parent `tr` of clicked `td` along with  **[.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)** to get the index of this `tr` :

```
$('table tr td').click(function() {
    var row_clicked = $(this).closest('tr').index(); // or $(this).parent().index();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    $('table .arrow').click(function(e){
    var trindex=$(this).parent().parent().index();
    alert(trindex);
});
```

**[SAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tn58J/)**

Answer (score 0):

Ah why did you delete your old question I almost had it done writing. So I'll wirte it once again.

assuming "this" is your clicked cell

```
var td = this;
var i_td = 0;
while( (td = td.previousSibling) != null ) 
  i_td++;

var i_tr = 0;
var tr = td.parentNode;
while( (tr = tr.previousSibling) != null ) 
  i_tr++;
```

your clicked row is i_tr and column is i_td, you can store this in your cookie from previous question and on document ready just call the `yourtableselector.childNodes[i_tr].childNodes[i_td]` and you have your previously clicked cell :)

Comment: Sorry. I thought that question was vague. I can do `$ ( 'tr:nth-child(row_number) .arrow' ).hide();` if I just get the row number.

Comment: exactly :) Now you can have the exact column also. BR

Comment: I mean, it wasn't vague. But it was too short "online" and exactly refers to your approach to select it afterwards :D

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
$('table td').click(function() {
  row_clicked = $(this).closest('tr').index();
});
```

Comment: @ChankeyPathak: can you share the fiddle

Comment: @ChankeyPathak:there are some errors on page. can you just post the relevant code.

Comment: Those are not affecting the functionality.

Comment: Strange, in fiddle it's showing correct row, whereas in my case it shows -1.

Comment: The fiddle i have provided you is modified. i made the changes on line 79. see them

Comment: I took that modified code in application, cleared cache and all, but still getting -1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first add class to the table or if you already have it use the same.
Or you directly use 'table' or table's Id.

I'll provide small example.

```
  <table border='1' class='abc'>
<tr>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td>        
  <td>50</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td>      
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
</table>




 $('.abc').find('tr').click(function(){
    console.log("row clicked "+($(this).index()+1));


});
```

Answer (score 0):

by clicking on that arrow you can get the same thing.
try this.

```
$('.arrow').click(function(){
console.log($(this).parent().parent().index());
});
```

Comment: getting -1 onclicking